# Xamarin Forms in HamburgerMenu System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Use this code to get the page user wants to go. What is wrong?

```
Page page = null;

                var item = e.SelectedItem as HamburgerMenuMenuItem;
                if (item == null)
                    return;
                var tempType = item.TargetType;
                if (tempType != null)
                {
                    page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(tempType);
                    page.Title = item.Title;
                }
```

Comment: Your page's constructor probably threw an exception. Try looking there.

Comment: @WillDecker seems like it can't Initialize Component. Thx for the direction.

Comment: No problem, sounds like you're using a xaml page. Try looking for issues in your xaml. Try enabling XamlCompilation to discover xaml issues at build time.

Comment: Thanks for recommendations, have already started xaml diagostics.

Comment: When asking on StackOverflow, please indicate in the question what the specific problem you're having is, rather than just pasting in non-working code with no explanation.